# Dialer in landscape mode

Tags: android, landscape

I have written a dock app that utilizes the stock dialer within android but it always displays in portrait mode is there a snippet that I must include to get the dialer to respond to being in the dock. How do I call the layout that the stock dock program does?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the user to put it in a dock, I suppose. If the device is in landscape mode, and the application does not support landscape mode (e.g., the dialer on my Nexus S), that is just the way it is.

More generally, you have no right to dictate how third party applications should look and behave, any more than other people have the right to dictate how your application should look and behave. The application will look and behave how its developers designed. If they have different layouts for landscape or being in some sort of dock, they will use those layouts... when they are in landscape or in some sort of dock.

Comment: This is not a third party application as I am writing it. I am asking how to change my own app.

Comment: @john murphy: No, you are not. The "stock dialer within android" is not in your own app.

Comment: oh i see what your saying. Your right it's not.... in that respect. However I see the car dock dialer shown in landscape mode. Do you know how this is accomplished -or- is there a way to link to that dialer?

Comment: @john murphy: That dialer layout is presumably only loaded when in a car dock. Again, that's up to the Dialtacts application to choose what layout to use in what situations.

Comment: Normally my phone defaults to landscape.